# What are the gods of the vikings in Charles Stross' "Merchant Princes"?

Tags: merchant-princes

The *Merchant Princes* series by Charles Stross posits a parallel world where North America was settled by Vikings.  What are the gods of their religion that are mentioned?  (It seems they are used mostly for swearing...)  I have these four so far: Sky Father, Lightning Child, Crone Wife, Trickster Cousin - what are the others?

Now I found also Sky Lady and Sister Corn, I think.  (But who they are could also be interesting.)

---

*Invisible Sun* (2021) mentions these: Lightning Child, On-Eyed Father, Eagle Mother.

Comment: Do you mean who they are? Sky Father is Odin, Lightning Son is Thor, and Trickster Cousin is Loki. Not sure about Crone Wife: she should be Frigg, but Frigg’s not really a crone.

Comment: @Adamant Are you confusing Frigg with Freyja? Odin is no spring chicken; it wouldn't be surprising for his spouse to be of a like age.

Comment: @chepner - Are you? Freya’s husband is Óðr. But that said, many hypothesize that they’re the same deity.

Comment: Odin is Óðinn in Old Norse; Óðr is a separate deity (ignoring the possible identifications  of Óðinn with Óðr and Frigg with Freyja).

Comment: @chepner - Right. But Frigg is generally said to be Odin’s wife.

Comment: Actually "Lightning Child" not "Son" it seems.  (Edited)

Comment: @Adamant Oh! Sorry, I agree with that. My point was that it's not that surprising to refer to Frigg as a crone (especially in an alternate conception of the pantheon), given that she is Odin's wife. (Referring to Freyja as a crone would certainly seem to be a stretch.)